# C realloc segmentation fault with appending char * to char **

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, segmentation-fault, realloc

I'm having trouble with the following code, which appends a char * to a char** by allocating more space.

```
size_t appendToken(char *tokens[], char *token, size_t size, size_t cap)
{
    if(size>=cap)
    {
        cap+=512;
        tokens = realloc(tokens, cap*sizeof(char *));
    }
    tokens[size] = token;
    return cap;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault when this code executes and size = cap (if there is remaining capacity, it behaves as expected). I've traced everything else, and it all behaves as expected. here is how tokens and token are initiated:

```
size_t tokenCount=0, tokens_cap = 5;
char **tokens = malloc(tokens_cap*sizeof(char *));
size_t size = 0;
size_t capacity = 4;
char *token = malloc(capacity*sizeof(char));
```

and here is how the function is called:

```
token_cap = appendToken(tokens, token, tokenCount++, token_cap);
```

I'd greatly appreciate some help with this.

Comment: `*tokens = realloc(*tokens, cap*sizeof(char *));`

Comment: Do you realize your function is modifying a local variable?

Comment: Oh crap, I feel so stupid. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional indirection for the `tokens` parameter

```
size_t appendToken(char ***tokens, char *token, size_t size, size_t cap)
{
    if(size>=cap)
    {
        cap+=512;
        *tokens = realloc(*tokens, cap*sizeof(char *));
    }
    (*tokens)[size] = token;
    return cap;
}
```

Otherwise, the outside code would access the *previously* allocated, and now freed, memory.

You will then call this as

```
token_cap = appendToken(&tokens, token, tokenCount++, token_cap);
```

Comment: Oh, here comes a three-star programmer! I think OP should revise his design, 3 levels of indirection is rarely *really* necessary.

Comment: @H2CO3 And where is your answer hiding? ;-)

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is wrong, because it answers what OP asked for and so it solves the problem (for now, at least). Anyway without some context (we don't really know **what** this will be used for) it's hard to decide what to redesign. Probably OP himself should decide on that.